# Error "spotify-api@0.0.17 /index.d.ts is not a module"

Tags: typescript, spotify

I've installed

> pnpm i -D  @types/spotify-api

But when I tried to import a type like

> import type { CurrentUsersProfileResponse } from 'spotify-api';

I've got this nasty error:

> "spotify-api@0.0.17 /index.d.ts is not a module"

What's the problem?